# Writes to MongoDB are lost when primary node changes in a shard replicaset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-replica-set

I am using nodejs driver to write to MongoDB cluster. The cluster is on kubernetes with 2 mongos replicas, 4 shards with PSS setup each and config server with PSS setup as well.

My application (nodejs) connects to mongos (mongos replicas are behind kubernetes service) which then writes/reads from shards. All works fine until I simulate a failover i.e. shutdown the primary pod in one of the shard replica (which is also the primary shard for the database). When primary fails, one of the secondary steps up as primary and the failed pod is restarted by kubernetes, as expected. But then what I observe is that none of the writes are actually reflecting into the collection even though the results show as success from nodejs app (with `acknowledged: true` and inserted ids in the result).

I could also confirm from mongod logs on new primary that it received the writes and resulted in `nInserted: <some-number>` and no error. But when I query the collection itself then there are no entries after new primary was elected.

However, if I shutdown the newly elected primary of shard replica so that the old pod becomes the new primary once again, then all writes start to reflect in the collection correctly. Strange behaviour I am trying to get my head around, appreciate your suggestions.

MongoDB version: 5.0.2
NodeJs driver version: 4.9
Write concern used: majority
Read preference: primary (default)

Shards and config servers are statefulSets.
Mongos is a replicaSet of 2 pods.
NodeJS app connects to mongos via k8s service.
All shards (primary and secondaries headless service DNS names) are added to mongos.

**Update**:

From further troubleshooting, I found that the writes are lost only when the primary shard of a database loses its primary member of replica set and another member is elected as primary (everything works if other non-primary shards of the database lose their primary member).

Comment: "Inserted id" is calculated on the drive (nodejs) before data is even sent to mongo. Do you have an arbiter? Please ensure writeconcern writes to at least 2 nodes. It's "majority" by default, and with 3 nodes replica it acknowledges write when at least 1 secondary has the data.

Comment: @AlexBlex There is no arbiter, each shard has one primary and 2 secondaries. WriteConcern is 'majority'.

Comment: Then it should work. You will need to analyse logs to understand what happened exactly.  The update is a bit confusing. Shards are peers, what do you mean b "primary shard"?

Comment: MongoDB isn't complaining with errors (at least not in the logs). I can see the write requests going to shards and returning successfully i.e. MongoDB logs have messages that show how many docs inserted but nothing reflects in collection (I mentioned this in the question though). 
About "primary shard" in the update - that is the shard which holds all un-sharded collections for a particular database. As sharding is enabled on a per collection level in MongoDB, there may be some collections which are not sharded. Such collections stay in primary shard, chosen for a database (by mongos).

Comment: Fair enough. By analysing logs I meant reading through the primary election logs comparing timestamps to the journal. Missing data is not expected behaviour. Once you get the timeline of the failover events, writes and syncs, you can prepare a bug report to mongo team.